# treeview node event

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, treeview

I want to add a event to my `TreeView` after a user select a node.

```
For i = 0 To Informacion.Count - 1 Step +1
        arreglosplit = Informacion(i)

        Select Case arreglosplit(3)

            Case "ab"
                Dim nn As TreeNode = New TreeNode(arreglosplit(5).ToString)

                n0.Nodes.Add(nn)
            Case "bc"
                Dim nn As TreeNode = New TreeNode(arreglosplit(5).ToString)
                n1.Nodes.Add(nn)

            Case "cd"
                Dim nn As TreeNode = New TreeNode(arreglosplit(5).ToString)
                n2.Nodes.Add(nn)

            Case "de"
                Dim nn As TreeNode = New TreeNode(arreglosplit(5).ToString)
                n3.Nodes.Add(nn)
```

How to add the event after select set the text to a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AfterSelect`/`BeforeSelect` events. This is easily searchable on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx